# How to pass an argument to Ruby 'send' method inside javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript function inside my erb template:

```
function replaceNew(field_name){
  var el = document.getElementById('registrierung_' + field_name)
  el.value = <%= @abholstelle.send(field_name) %>
}
```

and got error:

```
undefined local variable or method 'field_name'
```

How can I pass that 'field_name'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot.   ruby runs on the server, long before the javascript runs on the client on the other side of the connection.  you would have to use AJAX to send the `field_name` to server.  btw, you're digging a security hole with that freewheeling `#send`.